# Can I use COUNTIF with a range of values (min, max)?

Tags: google-sheets

Just wondering if it is possible or which equation to use if I want to calculate certain values between them and return how many meet those criteria.

For example: I have values in multiple columns being entered as times from 900 to 1800. Now I want the COUNTIF to return the values which fall greater than 1415 but not greater than 1615.

Is this possible?

Currently this is what I have in place:

```
=COUNTIF(C10:AA10, ">1415")
```

The problem is I need it to only count values between 1415 and 1615. Not sure how to express this in the function.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`countifs`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256550?hl=en) with plural "s". Its arguments must alternate between ranges and conditions, like so:

```
=COUNTIFS(C10:AA10, ">1415", C10:AA10, "<=1615")
```